# Changing the text color of Facebook like button

Tags: html, css, facebook-like

I added Facebook like button to my site, but the text color is too dark and the background is black, so it is very hard to read what is says ("xyz people like this").
 Can anyone tell me how to fix this? 
defining some additional class maybe?
nothing comes to my mind.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook button can be set with dark or light background

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Just change the color scheme to "dark" and it will fit your dark background.

Comment: Thanks Aaviya, It sovles the problem! :)